# Count the number of elements different in one set than the other

Tags: c++, stl, count, set-difference

The [set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)  algorithm gives you output of elements which are in the first range and not in second. Is there a algorithm which will just give me the count and not the difference.

I understand I can implement my own version of the algorithm described in the link or I can count the number of elements after I get the result. Is there a existing API which will do it for me efficiently.

Thanks

Comment: You may create an "`CounterIterator`".

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write your own OutputIterator-like thing that you could pass into `std::set_difference`. An OutputIterator needs to be dereferencable, assignable, and incrementable. Note also that `std::set_difference` returns an OutputIterator, so we can take advantage of that by making it convertible to `int`.

Hence something like:

```
struct CountingIterator
    : std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, int>
{
    template <typename T>
    CountingIterator& operator=(T&& ) {
        ++count;
        return *this;
    }

    CountingIterator& operator*() { return *this; }
    CountingIterator& operator++() { return *this; }

    operator int() { return count; }

    int count = 0;
};
```

Which, when modifying the example in [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) yields:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 9};
    std::vector<int> v2 {2, 5, 7};

    int count = 
        std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                        CountingIterator());

    std::cout << count << std::endl; // prints 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an operation such trivial that doesn't require a specific method. If you can't afford to allocate a temporary set to compute the difference and then get their size, just compute it with `std::accumulate` or `std::for_each`:

```
unordered_set<int> set1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
unordered_set<int> set2 = {2,4,6};    
size_t count = set1.size() - std::accumulate(set1.begin(), set1.end(), 0, [&set2](size_t previous, int value) { return set2.count(value) + previous; });
```

But if you don't have any specific requirement or huge sets doing `set_difference` + `size()` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an "`CountingIterator`" as `OutputIterator`, something like:

```
struct CountingIterator
{
    CountingIterator& operator*() { return *this; }  

    CountingIterator& operator ++() { return *this; }
    CountingIterator& operator ++(int) { return *this; }

    template <typename T>
    CountingIterator& operator =(const T&) { ++counter; return *this; }

    int counter = 0;
};
```